# How can I insert System.windows.forms.datagridview to my dialog?

Tags: mfc, datagridview, dialog

I want to insert datagridview to my dialog.

So I added it, after this, 15 error occured. Why is this?

Here is code.

```
// AccessDlg.h : header file
//

#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

// CAccessDlg dialog
class CAccessDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
    CAccessDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ACCESS_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    CWinFormsControl<System::Windows::Forms::DataGridView> m_DataGridView;

// Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

void CAccessDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_ManagedControl(pDX, IDC_GridView, m_DataGridView);
}
```

Error is like this.

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C3083: 'Windows': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
error C3083: 'Forms': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
error C2039: 'DataGridView' : is not a member of 'System'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you including afxwinforms.h? You should have added the following to stdafx.h

```
#include <afxwinforms.h>
```